# In Java, why does a child stored as a parent call the parent's static methods, but access the child's static data members?

Tags: java, inheritance, static

Say you have two classes as follows:

```
class A{
  static int statint = 5;
  int instanceint = 5;
  public void instanceMethod(){}
  public static void staticMethod(){}
}

class B extends A{
  static int statint = 6;
  int instanceint = 6;
  public void instanceMethod(){}
  public static void staticMethod(){}
}
```

and then you instantiate as follows:

```
public static void main(String[] args){
  A basa =new B();  //child(B) stored as parent(A) type
  int i=basa.statint; /**gives you (child)B's static data member (6)**/
  int j=basa.instanceint; //gives you (parent)A's instance data member (5)
  basa.instanceMethod(); //calls (child)B's instanceMethod() version. 
  basa.staticMethod();   /**call's (parent)A's staticMethod() version.**/
}
```

My question is:  Why can the child's static methods hide the parent's static data members, but not the parent's static methods?  I would think that it would be neither or both.

(I'm aware of ways around this - e.g. for static data member/method access, use `ClassName.datamember` or `ClassName.method()` notation to ensure the proper version is called, and for instance variables, explicitly downcast the child to be stored in the child type when accessing variables, as with `((B)basa).instanceint;`, to get B's instance data member -
My question is more for my own understanding of why the defaults don't seem to be consistent for hidden static data members and hidden static methods accessed from an instance.)

Comment: [Can't reproduce.](http://ideone.com/lKddAK)

Comment: It doesn't. You are mistaken.

Answer (score 1):

Actually your comment:

```
/** gives you (child)B's static data member (6) **/
```

is wrong. The value of i is 5 and Java is consistent here.

Comment: I'm sorry.  It must have been something in my code.